# Cannot Resolve OpenAI API getCompletion Error After Trying Online Solutions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, openai-api

I was working on building a react app, but I get this error constantly from openAI.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

I have correctly set-up a valid API key in the environment so that's not the problem.

```
export default class Ai {
    constructor() {
        this.url = "https://api.openai.com/v1";
        this.max_tokens = 2048;
        this.model = "text-davinci-003";
        this.temperature = 0.9;
        this.top_p = 0;
        this.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY;
    }

    async getCompletion(prompt) {
        const path = `${this.url}/completions`;
        const response = await fetch(`${path}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.apiKey}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                model: this.model,
                prompt: prompt,
                temperature: this.temperature,
                max_tokens: this.max_tokens,
                top_p: this.top_p,
            }),
        });
        try {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data.choices[0].text;
        } catch (error) {
            return `${error}`;
        }
    }
}
```

where I call this function and create object for this class is also correct use but I didn't include here not to clutter this question with codes. I have gone through every possible solution on the internet but none of them came through, most of which included that there were problem with the header.

Comment: I've debugged this a lot and realized that the problem was the prompt exceeding 4096 tokens. So it's resolved now.